# Bodies not colliding properly in Box2D(LibGDX)

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d, shapes

So, in my game I have a box2D dynamic body with a polygon shape as my player and a box2D static body with a chain shape as a static box. The debug renderer is showing all the boxes correctly. When the player collides with the box from the top, it collides, but when from either side, it goes right trough. I have tried to use polygons for the static boxes, but it acts weirdly. I can't figure out what's wrong.

Here is the code:

player body and fixture definition:

```
        bdef=new BodyDef();
        bdef.position.set((WIDTH/2+169)/PPM,100/PPM);
        bdef.type=BodyType.DynamicBody;
        body=world.createBody(bdef);

        PolygonShape shape=new PolygonShape();
        shape.setAsBox(16/PPM,16/PPM);

        fdef=new FixtureDef();
        fdef.shape=shape;
        fdef.filter.categoryBits=B2DVars.BIT_PLAYER;
        fdef.filter.maskBits=B2DVars.BIT_BLOCK;
        body.createFixture(fdef).setUserData("player");
```

static box body and fixture definition:

```
            bdef=new BodyDef();
            fdef=new FixtureDef();
            bdef.type=BodyType.StaticBody;
            bdef.position.set((col+0.5f)*tileSize/PPM,(row+0.5f)*tileSize/PPM);

            ChainShape chainShape=new ChainShape();
            Vector2[] v=new Vector2[5];
            v[0]=new Vector2(-tileSize/2/PPM,-tileSize/2/PPM);
            v[1]=new Vector2(tileSize/2/PPM,-tileSize/2/PPM);
            v[2]=new Vector2(tileSize/2/PPM,tileSize/2/PPM);
            v[3]=new Vector2(-tileSize/2/PPM,tileSize/2/PPM);
            v[4]=new Vector2(-tileSize/2/PPM,-tileSize/2/PPM);
            chainShape.createChain(v);

            fdef.friction=0;
            fdef.shape=chainShape;
            fdef.isSensor=false;
            fdef.filter.categoryBits=B2DVars.BIT_BLOCK;
            fdef.filter.maskBits=B2DVars.BIT_PLAYER;
            world.createBody(bdef).createFixture(fdef).setUserData("block");
```

EDIT: The problem is no more, it was a problem with me setting the player position by transforming, but now I don't know, how to else make the player move when I push a button and stop when I release it?

Comment: Can you add the code that deals with the collisions?

Comment: It's Box2D. Isn't the colliding done in the libraries already?

Comment: You can add a `ContactListener` to your box2d world where you deal with the collisions (as explained in the wiki: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/box2d#contact-listeners). From your comment I understand you did not do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving a `DynamicBody` should not be done via `setTransform`. The smoothest way to set a `DynamicBody` position is via `MouseJoint`, but whether or not it'll help you depends on what kind of movement you are after. This [example](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/Box2DTest.java) is an excellent place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Use contact listener in this way to check the collision

```
'if((contact.getFixtureA().getBody() == bodyEdgeScreen &&
                        contact.getFixtureB().getBody() == body2)
                        ||
                        (contact.getFixtureA().getBody() == body2 &&
                                contact.getFixtureB().getBody() == bodyEdgeScreen))'
```